# Github branch issues- IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, terminal

I am using IntelliJ 15, version control with Github, and Zsh. I am having issues when switching branches. My goal is to copy all content from the gh-pages branch to my master branch.

I start by trying to switch branches. I get the same error when using the "git merge gh-pages" command.

[image]

So I try to push the changes.

[image]

...

[image]

But if I try to checkout or merge it gives me the same error.

The misc or workspace files don't have any merge issues.

[image]

What's the deal?

Thanks, base2101

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that you haven't pushed the changes, but that you haven't *committed* them. Do `git add .`, followed by `git commit`, then should be fine.